# E.M. Gabidulin's "Theory of codes with maximum rank distance" article in English

Tags: reference-request, coding-theory

I am trying to find a legible digital copy in English of the following paper:

E. M. Gabidulin. $\textbf{Theory of codes with maximum rank distance}$. Problemy Peredachi Informatsii, 21(1):3–16, 1985.

My search so far only returned the original article in Russian, or some very bad-quality pdfs (in terms of legibility), is there a well-written translated copy in English?

Edit: here is the translated text I found: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235008632_Theory_of_codes_with_maximum_rank_distance_translation

Comment: Tell us where you got the "bad quality pdfs" from. They may well be from the English version of the journal, in which case I don't hold high hopes for what you want, unless someone bothered to re-latex the translation.

Comment: @kodlu Edited question to include source

Comment: OK, that's the scan of a bad photocopy indeed. My insitution does not have access to the English translations of PPI [newer years are under springerlink but older years were from the Translators bureau in NY who translated Soviet journals]. Perhaps inter library loan might help